# How to restrict time on Day view

Tags: fullcalendar

on the Day view, the FullCalendar shows available times from 0 to 24.
I need to show only certain times (from 8 to 18).
How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the [Agenda Options](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/) you can set [minTime](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/minTime/) and [maxTime](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/maxTime/).

minTime - Determines the starting time that will be displayed, even when the scrollbars have been scrolled all the way up.

maxTime - Determines the end time (exclusively) that will be displayed, even when the scrollbars have been scrolled all the way down.